# Mock same method with different return value called twice in a function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a method to be tested using pytest. The method is calling same database model twice.

```
 def function:
    ids = database_model.object.filter(user="user1").filter(group="admin").values_list(ids, flat=True).allow_filtering()
    response_list = []
    unquie_ids = list(set(ids))
    for ids in unique_ids:
        response = database_model.object.filter(ids=ids).limit(1)
        for res in response:
            temp_dict = {}
            temp_dict['name'] = res.name
            temp_dict['description'] = res.description
            response_list.append(temp_dict)
   return response_list
```

This works well. I am tring to write unit test case for this.
As the same database_model requires return value twice. It does not work for me.

```
  @patch('database_model')
  def test_function(mock_model):
      mock_model.objects.filter.return_value.filter.return_value.values_list.return_value.allow_filtering_return_value = [Mock_id]
      mock_model.objects.filter.limit.return_value = mock_dict

      response = function()

      assert len(response) > 0
```

mock_id and mock_dict are values created for test case.
My question is first time i am assigning a return_value to mock_model.objects.filter.return_value.filter.return_value.values_list.return_value.allow_filtering.return_value to [Mock_id] which gets assigned properly. But the next line i am trying to assign a return_value again to the same method. This takes as a magic mock object. So my test case fails because it is getting a empty list. I would like to know how can i assign two different return_values to the same method.

Comment: With `side_effect`? Have you tried reading the docs?

Comment: I tried using side_effect. It did not work. My return_vale for the first time is for filter.filter.values_list.return_value while for the second time it is for filter.limit.return_value

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a clearer description of the problem that *"did not work"*.

Comment: Sorry for not being complete example. I have edited my post. Please see if it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a `side_effect` for `database_model.object.filter` mock that gives you a `Mock()` configured to return the correct `ids` list after a mock to use in for cycle.

```
mock_filter_get_ids = Mock()
mock_filter_ids = Mock()
mock_model.objects.filter.side_effect = [mock_filter_get_ids, mock_filter_ids]
mock_filter_get_ids.filter.return_value.values_list.return_value.allow_filtering_return_value = [Mock_id]
mock_filter_ids.limit.return_value = mock_dict
```

## But...

Forget it: refactor your code, at least extract:

```
database_model.object.filter(user="user1").filter(group="admin").values_list(ids, flat=True).allow_filtering()
```

In something like `get_user_ids()` and

```
database_model.object.filter(ids=ids).limit(1)
```

in `get_ids_response()`.

You can mock the new methods and make your code simpler to read, simple to test means simple to read almost every time.

Comment: Thanks Michele. I refactored my code. That was much easier and simpler.